# Javascript: Calling private in a outside javascript file with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to call the method getTitulo, getDuracion and getLink inside the cancion.js file but when i call the function it returns the following error: "listaCanciones_Lcl[i].getTitulo is not a function". I have searched in different websites but i didnt got lucky with finding an answer. Hopefully someone here can give me some help, i will gladly appreciate it!

//Logic.js file

```
 var listaCanciones = [],
 ejecuTitulo = '',
 ejecuDuracion = '',
 ejecuLink = '';


var btnGenerarLista = document.getElementById("addList").addEventListener("click", agregarCanc);
var btnAgregarLista = document.getElementById("gnrList").addEventListener("click", llenarTabla);

function agregarCanc (){

var nameSong = document.querySelector('#nameSong').value;
var duraSong = document.querySelector('#duraSong').value;
var linkSong = document.querySelector('#linkSong').value;
var objCancion = new Cancion(nameSong, duraSong, linkSong);
listaCanciones.push(objCancion);

var listaCancionesJson = JSON.stringify(listaCanciones);

localStorage.setItem('json_canciones', listaCancionesJson);

}


function llenarTabla (titulo){

var celdaTitulo = document.querySelector('#tituloList'),
    celdaDuracion = document.querySelector('#duracionList'),
    celdaLink = document.querySelector('#linkList'),
    listaCanciones_Lcl = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('json_canciones'));

for(var i=0; i<listaCanciones_Lcl.length;i++){

// Acceder a lista canciones
```

I am getting an error in this line, where is says "getTitulo" is not a function but i dont really know why?

```
var nodoTextoTitulo = document.createTextNode(listaCanciones_Lcl[i].getTitulo()),
    nodoTextoDuracion = document.createTextNode(listaCanciones_Lcl[i].getDuracion()),
    nodoTextoLink = document.createTextNode(listaCanciones_Lcl[i].getLink());

// Create td

var elementoTdTitulo = document.createElement('td'),
    elementoTdDuracion = document.createElement('td'),
    elementoTdLink = document.createElement('td');

// Celda Id Append Child

elementoTdTitulo.appendChild(nodoTextoTitulo);
elementoTdDuracion.appendChild(nodoTextoDuracion);
elementoTdLink.appendChild(nodoTextoLink);

// Fila Append Child

celdaTitulo.appendChild(elementoTdTitulo);
celdaDuracion.appendChild(elementoTdDuracion);
celdaLink.appendChild(elementoTdLink);

}

}
```

//Cancion.js File

```
var Cancion = function(pTitulo, pDuracion, pLink){


var id = 0;
var titulo = pTitulo;
var duracion = pDuracion;
var link = pLink;


this.getId = function (){
    return id;
};

this.setTitulo = function (pTitulo){
    titulo = pTitulo;
};
this.getTitulo = function(){
    return titulo;
};

this.setDuracion = function(pDuracion){
    duracion = pDuracion;
};
this.getDuracion = function(){
    return duracion;
};

this.setLink = function (pLink){
    link = pLink;
};
this.getLink = function(){
    return link;
};
};
```

Comment: JSON is only for primitive datatypes like Strings, Numbers, Boolean, Arrays and Object.. You cannot store functions in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are loading the Cancion.js file before the others in your HTML. Your problem is that when you parse the JSON back out of local storage, `Cancion` is not a known object, so `getTitulo` is undefined. You'll have to do `listaCanciones_Lcl[i].titulo;` instead.

And another change you'll need is to loosen the scope of your variables. The reason you need `this.x = pX` is because before `JSON.stringify(new Cancion(1, 2, 3))` just returned `"{}"`. With this code it returns `"{"id":0,"titulo":1,"duracion":2,"link":3}"`, which I think is what you were after.

```
function Cancion(pTitulo, pDuracion, pLink){
    this.id = 0;
    this.titulo = pTitulo;
    this.duracion = pDuracion;
    this.link = pLink;

    this.getId = function (){
        return this.id;
    };

    this.setTitulo = function (pTitulo){
        this.titulo = pTitulo;
    };

    this.getTitulo = function(){
        return this.titulo;
    };

    this.setDuracion = function(pDuracion){
        this.duracion = pDuracion;
    };

    this.getDuracion = function(){
        return this.duracion;
    };

    this.setLink = function (pLink){
        this.link = pLink;
    };

    this.getLink = function(){
        return this.link;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var objWithFunction = {
  name: 'Object with Function',
  getName: function() {  return this.name }
};
undefined
objWithFunction.getName() // --> "Object with Function"

var string = JSON.stringify(objWithFunction)
string // -=> "{"name":"Object with Function"}"
```

JSON is for data only..

Better you create a model, and fill it with data.. but this model has to exist in your application.. or you load the model parallel to your data..

```
function SomeThing() {};
SomeThing.prototype.getName = function() { return this.name };

var Thing1 = new SomeThing(JSON.parse("{name:'ThingOne'}"));
Thing1.getName(); // ThingOne
```